# How to write argument into a file.

Tags: java, file, arguments

I need make file of food. If i want add item to a file as argument using Formatter.format(), eclipse saying me

> The method format(String, Object[]) in the type Formatter is not applicable for the arguments 
>    (String, String, int, int)

What is solusion of my problem? What is the best way to save data in file as argument?

Here is code:

```
package program_skuska;

import java.util.Formatter;

public class Food {
    private int protein; 
    private int carbohyd; 
    private String name;
    private Formatter x; 

    public void create_foodDatabaze(){
        try{
            x = new Formatter("food_databaze.txt");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("It is a error");
        }
    }

    public void food_add(String name, int carbohyd, int protein){
        this.name = name; 
        this.carbohyd = carbohyd; 
        this.protein = protein; 

         x.format("%s %s %s", name, carbohyd, protein);
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be `format(String, Object...)`, not `format(String, Object[])`. It's a strange error, since I copied your code, and I didn't get the same error. Consider upgrading Eclipse. You might also check your jdk.

Comment: After change jdk code is alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "%d" in the format method for the integer. Ordinals are used after the initial "%" symbol, starting at 1.

```
x.format("%s %1d %2d", name, carbohyd, protein);
```